# AFP is much slower than Samba... How can this be?

Tags: mac-osx, samba, apple, truenas, afp

I got a FreeNAS Server running (FreeNAS 8RC2) with a raidz1 ZFS pool that shares a volume with both AFP and SAMBA to multiple Mac (All running Snow Leopards 10.6.6).

After some testing, I've noticed that after a while, the AFP performance degrades from 30-40 mbps or 7-8 mbps while SAMBA is able to sustain it (At least, it has not degraded until now.)

I candidly assumed that AFP would be somewhat faster (or at least equivalent) than Samba. I therefore assume that is something wrong with my setup for AFP...

After googling, I've applied the following on my Macs:

```
defaults write -g com.apple.AppleShareClient -dict-add afp_wan_threshold -int 50
defaults write -g com.apple.AppleShareClient -dict-add afp_wan_quantum -int 131702
```

However, it did not make any difference... Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The AFP stack for Linux, upon which FreeNAS is built, is not nearly as robust as Samba is. Because NetAtalk has a much smaller client base pounding on it than Samba does, the rate of code improvement is slower and the push to optimize the code is not nearly as intense. The problems you note are very likely due to code-maturity differences between Samba and Netatalk.

Answer (score 1):

Netatalk on linux is old, very old. You can use Samba on your macs too, it has just a few problems and generally works great. The biggest issue is most probably file name limit, because nowadays almost nobody uses old fashioned software which creates files with data in resource forks.